# C++ inline assembler. How to read a value with the two lines?

Tags: c++, assembly

Reading an address and reading a value by that address:

```
int m, n, k;
m = 7;
k = (int)&m;
n = *(int*)k;
```

Last line is compiled by Visual Studio 2013 to:

```
mov eax, k
mov eax, [eax]
mov n, eax
```

when the best variant is:

```
mov eax,[k]
mov n,eax
```

But the code below is not working because `[k]` is interpreted as `k`:

```
__asm {
  mov eax,[k]
  mov n,eax
}
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: The addressing mode you desire does not exist.

Comment: you can't load memory where the address is also in memory in x86.  the address must be in a register.

Comment: Note that storing the value of a pointer in an int is not the best idea either.

Comment: `k` expands to something like `[ebp + 8]`. `[[ebp + 8]]` is not a valid operand.

Comment: `int *k; /*...*/ ; n = *k;` also produces three lines without two.

Comment: `mov eax, k` is already reading a value from an address to a register.

Comment: some compilers do not know how to access non local variable from inline asm !!! try to make k,n as an local variables (or under borland IDEs use var directive for it). then it should work ... (of course you have to access your heap segment to work properly)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do two indirections in one go. x86 doesn't support this.

When you are doing `n = *(int *)k;`, you are really reading the value of `k` and then reading the content of that memory location. Since the content of `k` is not in a register at this point, it needs to be loaded into a register, and then that register content stored in `n`.

If you had a PDP-11 or VAX processor, it does indeed have a `mov *(k), n` (it has opposite direction to Intel assembler, so will move from `k` on the left to `n` on the right).

But x86, ARM, MIPS, 29K, 68000, and most other processors don't support this addressing moded

Comment: Yes, I understood. C++ stores absolute addresses, not relative.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. You are trying to read the contents of the memory location indicated by `k`. This means you need to first get the contents of `k`, then read that memory location to get the `*k` value, and the store that in the location named `n`. It's two memory reads to get the `*k` value,  and one memory write to store `n`, no matter how you look at it.